# Finding Harmonic Function in the form $\phi(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I must find a harmonic function $u(x,y)$ of the form $\phi(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$

Let $u(x,y) = \phi(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$.
$$
\phi_x = \phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})((x+\frac{\sqrt(x^2+y^2))}{\sqrt(x^2+y^2)}  )
$$
\begin{align*}
\phi_{xx} &= \left (  \phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \right )' \left ((x+\frac{\sqrt(x^2+y^2))}{\sqrt(x^2+y^2)} \right ) + \left (\phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \right ) \left ( \frac{(x+\sqrt(x^2+y^2))}{\sqrt(x^2+y^2)}\right )'\\
&= \phi''(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\left (\frac{(x+\sqrt(x^2+y^2))}{\sqrt(x^2+y^2)} \right )^2 + \left (\phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \right ) \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} - \frac{2x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}\right )
\end{align*}
$$
\phi_y =\left ( \phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\right ) \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right )
$$
\begin{align*}
\phi_{yy} &= \left ( \phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\right )'\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right ) +  \left ( \phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\right )\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right )'\\
&= \phi''(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right )^2 +  \left ( \phi'(x + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\right ) \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} - \frac{2y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \right )
\end{align*}

This is obviously pretty convoluted so when I attempt to solve the DE discovered from the Laplacian Equation, I get lost. How do I make this more simple with a substitution?

Comment: You should try in polar coordinates!

Comment: @MassiveJack Meaning, let $x = \cos(t)$ and $y = \sin(t)$? Is it okay to assume we are on the unit circle? Or must I let $x = r\cos(t)$ and $y = r\sin(t)$?

Comment: Let $x=r\cos(t), y=r\sin(t)$, make this change of variables in your function and then use the expression of the Laplace operator in polar coordinates :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Coordinate_expressions

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks. Is there a quick way to check if $\phi$ is a constant function or not? I would like to be able to check that quickly before delving into a long process such as this.

Comment: It is not a very long road to obtain the equation, which seems to be $$2r(1+\cos(t))\phi''(z)+(1+\cos(t))\phi'(z)=0,$$ where $z=r(1+\cos(t))$. After that you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. You should obtain the equation: $$2z\phi''(z)+\phi'(z)=0,$$ with $z=r(1+\cos(t))$. Now, this is easy to solve!

Comment: Haha, I was typing out my comment to say that I had obtained something different after the substitution and then you made your update comment. We can let $\phi''(z) = y'(z)$. Then we have $y'(z) + 2z^{-1}y(z) = 0$ which is $\frac{dy}{dz} + 2z^{-1}y =0$. This is a separable equation. That is, $$\frac{dy}{y} = -2z^{-1}dz$$ Then we can continue to integrate and solve. Is this right?

Comment: Then we have $$\ln(y) = -2\ln(z) + C$$ which transforms into $y = \frac{1}{z^2} + C$. Then $\phi'(z) = z^{-2}$ and then $\phi(z) =\int \frac{1}{z^2} = -\frac{1}{z}+ C= \frac{1}{r(1+\cos(t))} + C = $

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question on here as I am studying Complex Analysis independently and was looking for something not typically found on the books, but see that the answer is still "up in the air". As Massive Jack said, the key is to use polar coordinates to transform the given multi-variable function to one dependent on $r$ and $\theta$ , which yields the ordinary differential equation (ODE) above, dependent only on the variable $z$ after making the substitution $z= r(1+cos(\theta))$. That's all correct and everything, but I just wanted to provide more details into how to obtain the final result after one obtains the ODE. As Complex, Oh did, you may want to proceed by reducing the order of the ODE to a first order ODE, but you'd end up obtaining (after letting $\phi'(z)$ = $y(z)$ and then $\phi''(z)$ = $y'(z)$) :   $2zy'(z)$ + $y(z)$ = $0$. I want to point out that there are no restrictions here on the variable $z$, so it is not always the case that you can divide like it was done above. ($cos(\pi$) = $-1$ ... ). With that small observation, note that then we proceed to solve the ODE , which is really a separable equation and whose solution can be readily be obtained as $y(z) = \frac{c}{\sqrt(z)}$

The final step is to put this in terms of $\phi(z)$, and thus we get that $\phi(z) = \int \frac{c}{\sqrt(z)}dz = c{\sqrt(z)}+ d$. You may then substitute back for $z$ as appropriate.